# Instantiating immutable paired objects

Tags: scala, object, immutability

Is it possible to create a class with an immutable reference to a partner object, or does it have to be a `var` that I assign after creation?

e.g.

```
class PairedObject (p: PairedObject, id: String) {
  val partner: PairedObject = p  // but I need ref to this object to create p!
}
```

or similarly how could I instantiate the following pair?

```
class Chicken (e: Egg) { 
  val offspring = e
}

class Egg (c: Chicken) {
  val mother = c
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a complete solution to the Chicken/Egg problem:

```
class Chicken (e: =>Egg) { 
  lazy val offspring = e 
}

class Egg (c: =>Chicken) {
  lazy val mother = c
}

lazy val chicken: Chicken = new Chicken(egg)
lazy val egg: Egg         = new Egg(chicken)
```

Note that you have to provide explicit types to the `chicken` and `egg` variables.

And for PairedObject:

```
class PairedObject (p: => PairedObject, val id: String) {
  lazy val partner: PairedObject = p
}

lazy val p1: PairedObject = new PairedObject(p2, "P1")
lazy val p2: PairedObject = new PairedObject(p1, "P2")
```

Comment: I added solution for PairedObject as well. Also I found that vals for `chicken` and `egg` don't need to be lazy. Strictly you don't need to include types for both, as one can be inferred.

Comment: This solution will work if entered at the top level of a `class` or `object` definition, but one gets an illegal forward reference error if `chicken` and `egg` are local variables (say, inside a function). A solution that works in any scope is: `lazy val (egg: Egg, chicken: Chicken) = ...`, which can be self-referential.

Comment: @KiptonBarros -- I think you should write up your comment as an answer, because, sorry Eric, as ingenious as the response was, it was woefully incomplete without KB's improvement.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510060/explain-this-type-mismatch-in-lazy-evaluation) for more.

Comment: @Malvolio that was my fault: I tested this in 2.9 in an `App` object which explains why `lazy` was not required. More generally it will be within a function where it is, as @Kipton points out. I've editied it back to Eric's original.

Comment: This is a good solution, but note that the lazy val is a little bit of "cheating", because the compiler generates a variable that can be internally mutated once (on first access).

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is circular references, you could use the solution posted in this SO question:

[scala: circular reference while creating object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978270/scala-circular-reference-while-creating-object)

This solves the chicken/egg problem.

Comment: Works well if I just have a couple of `case object`s: just make the val `lazy`.