# letrec in Scala? (Immutable way to "Tie the knot?")

Tags: scala, letrec, tying-the-knot

Suppose I have a stupid little case class like so:

```
case class Foo(name: String, other: Foo)
```

How can I define `a` and `b` immutably such that `a.other` is `b`, and `b.other` is `a`? Does scala provide some way to ["tie the knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot)? I'd like to do something like this:

```
val (a, b): (Foo, Foo) = (Foo("a", b), Foo("b", a)) // Doesn't work.
```

---

Possibilities

In Haskell I would do this:

```
data Foo = Foo { name :: String, other :: Foo }

a = Foo "a" b
b = Foo "b" a
```

Where the bindings to `a` and `b` are contained in the same `let` expression, or at the top level.

Or, without abusing Haskell's automagical letrec capabilities:

```
(a, b) = fix (\ ~(a', b') -> Foo "a" b', Foo "b" a')
```

Note the lazy pattern, `~(a', b')`, that's important.

Comment: I wonder how many search engines will now start finding this questions for "wedding"...

Comment: This question is more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects. Also, if it were possible with case classes the `toString` would recurse forever

Comment: @LuigiPlinge that solution infects the definition of the class itself. I'd like to see a solution where `Foo` is unchaged. `toString` would indeed recurse forever.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `Foo` to be unchanged, but laziness in Scala is on the declaration site. It is impossible for `Foo` to be non-strict without changing it, and the pattern indicated in Haskell only works because `Foo`, there, is non-strict (that is, `Foo "a" b` doesn't evaluate `b` immediately).

Otherwise the solution is pretty much the same, allowing for the hoops necessary to get everything non-strict:

```
class Foo(name: String, other0: => Foo) { // Cannot be case class, because that mandates strictness
  lazy val other = other0 // otherwise Scala will always reevaluate
}
object Foo {
  def apply(name: String, other: => Foo) = new Foo(name, other)
}

val (a: Foo, b: Foo) = (Foo("a", b), Foo("b", a))
```

Comment: Ah you're right. Defining `data Foo = Foo { name :: !String, other :: !Foo }` causes the Haskell solutions to not work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment "otherwise Scala will always reevaluate". That's good to know!