# Can this scala pattern for creating two mutually dependent objects be implemented more cleanly?

Tags: scala, refactoring

Suppose I have two data structures which both want a reference to the other.
I can't simply make each one a lazy val, and pass them into each other; a stack overflow occurs.

The solution I came up with is something like:

```
class Alpha((deferredBeta: Alpha) => Beta) {
   lazy val beta = deferredBeta(this)
}

class Beta(val alpha: Alpha) {}

def main {
   val alpha = Alpha(beta)
   val beta = (alpha: Alpha) => Beta(alpha)
}
```

Whilst it works, it seems a bit fragile, particularly when it comes to subclassing. Also, without good documentation it's not obvious what's being done.

Is there a cleaner solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating immutable paired objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects)

Comment: @KimStebel I think it probably is; however, I didn't find it when I looked for duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

I think this solution is the simplest:

```
class Alpha(_beta: => Beta) {
  lazy val beta = _beta
}

class Beta(_alpha: => Alpha) {
  lazy val alpha = _alpha
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Alpha
defined class Beta

scala> lazy val (alpha: Alpha, beta: Beta) = (new Alpha(beta), new Beta(alpha))
alpha: Alpha = <lazy>
beta: Beta = <lazy>

scala> alpha.beta
res2: Beta = Beta@4a40050

scala> beta.alpha
res3: Alpha = Alpha@38f18cc3
```

You could also add a factory for an alpha beta pair:

```
object AlphaBeta {
  def apply() = {
    lazy val tuple @ (alpha: Alpha, beta: Beta) = (new Alpha(beta), new Beta(alpha))
    tuple
  }
}

scala> AlphaBeta()
res13: (Alpha, Beta) = (Alpha@2a3fa87a,Beta@394df741)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asking for, but it works:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Alpha {
  self: Beta =>
  val beta: Beta = self
}

trait Beta {
  self: Alpha =>
  val alpha: Alpha = self
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Alpha
defined trait Beta

scala> val (alpha, beta) = {
     |   val ab = new Alpha with Beta
     |   (ab: Alpha, ab: Beta)
     | }
alpha: Alpha = $anon$1@13668e0b
beta: Beta = $anon$1@13668e0b

scala> alpha.beta
res0: Beta = $anon$1@13668e0b
```