# object cross-references and initialization order

Tags: scala, object, initialization, initialization-order

I have the following code:

```
abstract class SuperClass (cs: Seq[C]) {
  def init {}
}

object A extends SuperClass(Seq(B, C))
object B extends SuperClass(Seq(A, D))
object C extends SuperClass(Seq(A, B))
object D extends SuperClass(Seq(C, B, A))
object E extends SuperClass(Seq(B, A, B))

object Initializer {
  def init {
    A.init
    B.init
    C.init
    D.init
    E.init
  }
}
```

so at the beginning, because each object has inside some more things to initialize, I call

```
Initializer.init
```

and then at some point further in the program, when I use the `cs` parameter of an object, I get a `NullPointerException` because one of the objects referenced in the `Seq` is really `null` (printing out to the console shows that). Namely the references to the objects which have their `init` called later than the `init` of other objects that reference them, tend to be set to `null`.

This is an interesting situation. I have a supposedly any-to-any arbitrary cross-referencing here and I do not know how to properly realize the initialization without bringing it out to an external method completely (which is a break-down of encapsulation anyway). Especially that users might be given the ability to create their own singletons extending the `SuperClass` class.

Which is the best way to do this with as less boilerplate as possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating immutable paired objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects). In short: `abstract class SuperClass (cs: => Seq[SuperClass])`

Comment: @sschaef: umm.. have you tried that? I can't get it to work. The Seq is build prior to passing it as a by-name anyway. And according to the chicken-egg example, I have to make the Seq lazy when constructing it. But I am constructing it while passing it to the constructor, so I can't make it lazy. And defining it as lazy elsewhere does not look too attractive either... yeah, I just don't get it!

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? This works: https://gist.github.com/sschaef/4750334

Comment: @sschaef finally, I have succeeded in applying the proposed solution. The problem was that my code is far more complex than the example and I have missed some important changes in the code, needed to apply the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution. Well it's half a duplicate of [Instantiating immutable paired objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects), but the dependencies defined by Seq is an additional dimension.

```
abstract class SuperClass (cs: => Seq[SuperClass]) {
  SuperClass.collected += this
  def init {}
}
object SuperClass {
  private val collected = ListBuffer[SuperClass]()
  def init = collected.foreach(_.init)
}
object Initializer {
  def init {
    A // access the root object
    SuperClass.init // call init on all automatically created dependent objects
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have improved the initialization routine.. but seems like that does not solve the initialization order problem, as far as I understand it simply automates the initialization.. also see my comment to the sschaef's comment to the original question...

Comment: Who said the objects had to be initialized in order? Also - yes - my solution would only initialize those objects that are connected to A. But this is a bit more generic than initializing each object individually. And you probably would also have a starting point or root object to use in an application... so. It depends how the whole thing would be used. Your above comment states you don't get it - OK...